# Django test render_to_string() without request

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I want to write a test for my function:

```py
def render_email_body(ticket, action_type, comment):
    return render_to_string(
        action_to_body_template[action_type],
        {
            "issue_key": ticket.get_pk(),
            "comment": comment
        },
    )
```

Basically I want to check if generated text comes from `templates/emails/bodies/some_file.html` (`action_to_body_template[action_type]` points to the location of the file).
However [assertTemplateUsed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertTemplateUsed) function takes a request as a parameter. So my question is how can I check which template was used, without a request.

Comment: Would making a mock request not work for your case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I don't understand how can I use a mock request for this function.

Comment: use `from django.test.client import RequestFactory` or `mock.MagicMock`

Comment: As others suggested you can create a mock request object - thus construct the argument for the view without having to do a request. My question was wether this would work in your case or if it's something you did not know that it's possible.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. I'll read about it. Thank you